# What is the purpose of the sharp edges (aka mouse bites, aka perforated breakaway tabs) on the PCB?

Tags: pcb, edge, panelize

I have received an NVIDIA Jetson board this week and it has the following edges near the mount holes:

[image: Jetson edge]

I did a quick search on the internet but was only able to find similar edges on the Raspberry Pi Compute Module:

[image: Raspberry Pi Compute Module]

Could you please explain me why would you put those edges? I think it is for a better grip when mounted, but I fail to understand against which object the board will grip. Also, is there a standard for that, i.e. how do I design one for my boards in future if needed?

Comment: No purpose as such. These "sharp edges" are what is left over when the PCBs were manufactured in a panel using break-routing /break-off tabs.

Comment: Just like the holes around stamps !

Comment: Have a google search for "pcb mouse bites"

Comment: Thanks @efox29, I immediately found https://blogs.mentor.com/tom-hausherr/blog/tag/mouse-bite/ that has all information I might need beyond the SE answer!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PCBs are manufactured on a standard sized panel. Those sharp edges are often referred to as "mouse bites" and they are leftover after [depanelization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depaneling).

Here they are still hooked together:

[image]
<sub>(source: [xess.com](https://www.xess.com/static/media/uploads/blog/devbisme/2015-05-10/array_front.jpg))</sub>